# How to call the html.actionlink using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to call the actionlink using jquery , below is the code:

```
  $("#paycheck").click(function () {

        if ($("#terms").attr("checked")) {

       //Call Html.ActionLink // This is where the html.ActionLink should be called to display another view


        } else {
            alert("Please agree to the terms and conditions.");
            return false;
        }
    });

<%: Html.ActionLink("Pay", "Index", "News") %>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't *call an actionlink* using jQuery. You could send an AJAX request to the controller action this link is pointing to. If this is what you want, here's how to achieve 
it:

```
$(function() {
    $('#paycheck').click(function () {
        if ($('#terms').is(':checked')) {
            // Send an AJAX request to the controller action this link is pointing to
            $.ajax({
                url: this.href,
                type: 'GET',
                // you can send some additional data along with the request
                data: { foo: 'bar' },
                success: function(result) {
                    // TODO: process the results returned by the controller
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert('Please agree to the terms and conditions.');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Also make sure you provide a correct id (`paycheck`) to your action link when generating it

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Pay", "Index", "News", null, new { id = "paycheck" }) %>
```

But if it is only a matter of checking whether the user accepted the terms and conditions and then perform a standard redirect to the controller action without any AJAX, simply do this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#paycheck').click(function () {
        if ($('#terms').is(':checked')) {
            // by returning true you are letting the browser redirect to the link
            return true;
        }

        alert('Please agree to the terms and conditions.');
        // By returning false you stay on the same page and let the user
        // agree with the terms and conditions
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I want to display the Index view when paycheck id is clicked , along with passing some parameters to display on the view page

Comment: @Mr A, you want to do this using AJAX or simply redirect? I have shown you both approaches.

Comment: I dont know which is the best way of achieving it , I want to send an email when user click the cheque button, also displaying a new view which shows a message that an email has been sent which includes details of cheque payment

Comment: @Mr A, if you want to display a new view then the second approach is better as it will redirect the browser to this new page.

Comment: The second part of your answer is exactly what I was looking for Darin, thank you :)